# How to display image using onenote api?

Tags: php, onenote

I am using onenote api for get the Notebook, section and pages.
I have retrieved the  page content using onenote api. But Images are displaying broken link.

I got this error message when i try to retrieve the image using onenote api.

**OData Feature not implemented.**
Please advise how to solve this issue.

Thanks
Prabhu

Answer (score 0):

If the recalled page's content contains images, the html response will include img tags with src atttribute containing the uri of the resource, for example: https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/{id}/$value. You can then make a separate GET request to these endpoints to retrieve the binary contents of the images. Images won't render directly in a browser because they are private and require authorization to retrieve them (like the rest of the page content).

Could you make sure you are attempting to do a GET on a uri of the form I mentioned above. If you still hit errors, please provide the exact uri you are calling and the X-CorrelationId response header value.
Thanks

Comment: Yes i make separate GET request  to retrieve the binary content of image .  url : https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-5974b01690234c2a9dddd4ed2b59c36f!1-750AB09386EE9836!117/$value

Comment: Yes i make separate GET request  to retrieve the binary content of image .  url : https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-5974b01690234c2a9dddd4ed2b59c36f!1-750AB09386EE9836!117/$value


Resonse : HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented

Comment: Hi anyone please answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

yes I make a separate GET request to  retrieve the binary contents of the images

$url="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/resources/0-5974b01690234c2a9dddd4ed2b59c36f!1-750AB09386EE9836!117/$value";

Response : 
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-CorrelationId: 70069bfa-3fe2-4433-9a43-b7a6a09c8170
X-UserSessionId: 70069bfa-3fe2-4433-9a43-b7a6a09c8170
X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEnd_IN_2
X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.4028.1559
X-OfficeCluster: wus-www.onenote.com
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: s_id=70069bfa-3fe2-4433-9a43-b7a6a09c8170; expires=Thu, 30-Apr-2015 04:33:12 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Request-Processing-Time: 15.6314 ms
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 04:33:11 GMT
Content-Length: 149

{
  "error":{
    "code":"20111","message":"OData Feature not implemented. {0}.","@api.url":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=400828"
  }
}